# Dynamically set value of angular control from other controls

Tags: angular

I'm setting the value of my reactive form control in my Angular application like this:

```
<input type="number" #rate formControlName="rate">
<input type="number" #quantity formControlName="quantity">
<input type="number" [value]="quantity.value * rate.value" readonly formControlName="total">
        </mat-form-field>
```

Is this the right approach?  I noticed that if I show my form as json, the 'total' field is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **patchValue()** or **setValue()** to update the reactive forms

```
<input type="number" formControlName="rate" (change)="updateTotal()">
<input type="number" formControlName="quantity" (change)="updateTotal()">
<input type="number" readonly formControlName="total">
        </mat-form-field>
```

in **TS Code**

```
updateTotal(){
this.form.patchValue({
    total: Number(this.form.value.rate) * Number(this.form.value.quantity)
  });
}
```

[reference link](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use valueChange of Reactive Forms in this

HTML:

```
<input type="number" formControlName="rate">
<input type="number" formControlName="quantity">
<input type="number" readonly formControlName="total">
```

TS

```
  ngOnInit(){
        this.form.get('rate').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {this.CalculateTotal()})
        this.form.get('quantity').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {this.CalculateTotal()})
    }
    CalculateTotal(){
        this.form.patchValue({
            total: parseFloat(this.form.value.rate) * parseFloat(this.form.value.quantity)
        })
    }
```